# How to re-open a Connect IQ app from a background process?

Tags: garmin, connectiq

I want to write a mood tracker for my Garmin Fenix, so I want the app to pop up after some time interval, vibrate, and ask me for my current mood. Of course, I don't want to have the mood tracker in foreground all the time, so I'm looking for a way to re-open my app from a background task.

I found two modules which seem like they could achieve this, `Timer` and `Background`. `Background` can pass back data to the app after some time, but it can't vibrate and data transfer only takes effect once the app is manually re-opened. `Timer` doesn't seem to have much effect at all, once the app is closed – at least in the simulator.

What's the best way to re-open my app after a specific period of time?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand you could do as followes:

You want to use `[requestApplicationWake][1]`.

in the `onStop()` method you can register a temporalEvent.

```
Background.registerForTemporalEvent( 10 * 60 ); // 10 mins is the min
```

Then create this class that will be called when the event is triggered.

```
using Toybox.Background;
using Toybox.System;
using Toybox.Application.Storage;

(:background)
class BackgroundTimerServiceDelegate extends System.ServiceDelegate {

    function initialize() {
        ServiceDelegate.initialize();
    }

    function onTemporalEvent() {
        // do whatever processing you need and then serve the popup
        Background.requestApplicationWake("do you want to open the app?");          
    }
}
```

Comment: The Background.requestApplicationWake line needs to be followed by: Background.exit(null);